# Can we capture Firebase analytics event server side?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-analytics

Is it even possible to track events at server side? (Node.js)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics

Above shows it has client library for Web / Android / Ios.

Or there is another way to achieve something similar.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to emit events directly to Firebase Analytics from a backend.  Only the provided SDKs provide support for collecting events to be displayed in the console.

You are certainly free to capture your own events on the server, but you want to join that with data collected from the SDKs on the frontend, you will have to [export all that data to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7030014?hl=en), and merge it there.

Comment: Can you drop some code snippet or any reference link , how to capture events from server

Comment: Not really.  That's something you'll have to arrange on your own, according to your specific needs.